# Save product of a nested For Loop (Storage Grid)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, save, storage

I created a problem space through a nested loop.
I am trying to store the result (v_hat), so I can "call" a specific problem P(d,u) and get the corresponding 30 arrays.

```
outfile = TemporaryFile()
n = 10
w = np.random.normal(60, 3, n)
for d in range(10):
    r = np.random.uniform(0.1 * d, 0.2 * d)
    v = w * r
    for u in range(10):
        c = np.random.uniform(0.1 * u, 0.2 * u)
        sigma = v * c
        for j in range(30):
            v_hat = np.random.normal(v, sigma)  
            np.save(outfile, v_hat)
np.load(outfile)
```

I tried with np.save but it doesn't work, and even if it did, I wouldn't know how to call the specific P(d,u)

I would really appreciate it if someone could help! Thank you!

Comment: Is saving to a file really necessary? If not, just define a list outside of the loop and append each `v_hat` to that list.

Comment: I need to save it because I need to use it in other files too..

Comment: Why not take @matszwecja's suggestions of making a whole list and then save the whole list after the loop has finished completely? Why do you need to save it every iteration? Also, could you define `n`, please -- we can't run the code currently since we don't know what `n` is.

Comment: I edited the code to n = 10. I thought I have to save it because I have to extract a specific array every time. I am not really good at coding, so it is difficult to me to get the logic behind different methods..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the number of iterations in each nested loop (=10, 10, 30) and the shape of `v_hat` (= whatever `n` is), you could make `outfile` a NumPy array with shape `(10, 10, 30, n)`. Then during each iteration, you can replaced the appropriate row in `outfile` (where the appropriate row is `outfile[d][u][j]`) with `v_hat`.

Then at the end, you can save `outfile`. Here's the code:

```py
# You can set n to whatever you want; I tested for various n and the code always works
n = 8

# Make outfile the necessary size
outfile = np.zeros((10, 10, 30, n), dtype=float)

w = np.random.normal(60, 3, n)

for d in range(10):
    r = np.random.uniform(0.1 * d, 0.2 * d)
    v = w * r

    for u in range(10):
        c = np.random.uniform(0.1 * u, 0.2 * u)
        sigma = v * c

        for j in range(30):
            v_hat = np.random.normal(v, sigma)  

            # Index the appropriate row in outfile and replace with this iteration's v_hat
            outfile[d][u][j] = v_hat

# Save outfile to a txt file. Change the path as desired.
np.savetxt("file.txt", outfile)

# How to read in the txt. Make sure the path here and in the line above match
outfile_loaded = np.loadtxt("file.txt")
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more thing, if I save with np.savetext, it gives me: "ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 4D array instead". What should I do?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! You could replace `np.savetxt` with `np.save("file", outfile)` (do NOT add an extension). And to load, you could do `outfile_loaded = np.load("file.npy")`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` lets you make separate dimensions for `d`, `u` and your `n, 30` arrays, leaving you with one `(10, 10, n, 30)` array that can be indexed into (`out[d, u]`) to recover your needed array.  This can be saved as one organized array rather than a pile of un-indexed sub-arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def v_hat_gen(n, dmax, umax, i, fn = None):
    w = np.random.normal(60, 3, n)
    r = np.random.uniform(0.1 * np.arange(dmax), 0.2 * np.arange(dmax))
    v = np.einsum('i, jk -> ijk', r, w[None, :])
    c = np.random.uniform(0.1 * np.arange(umax), 0.2 * np.arange(umax), size = (umax, dmax)).T
    sigma = v*c[..., None]
    v_hat = np.random.normal(v[...,None], sigma[...,None], size = sigma.shape + (i,))
    if fn:
        with np.open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            np.save(f, v_hat)
    return v_hat

out = v_hat_gen(5, 10, 10, 30)
print(out.shape)

Out[]: (10, 10, 5, 30)
```

Comment: No problem.  I kind of dumped a lot of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) tricks in there, so if you have questions try to read up on that.  Also feel free to click the checkmark if it answers your question.